# Use different freetype libraries for GTK+ and Qt applications

Tags: fonts, libraries, gtk, qt

For Fedora, there is a [version](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/25/Everything/x86_64/os/repoview/freetype-freeworld.html) of the `freetype` library in RPM Fusion which has patented sub-pixel rendering enabled. I would like to use the default version of `freetype` for KDE/Qt applications and the RPM Fusion one for GTK+ applications, because the default version renders fonts better for KDE/Qt than for GTK+. The gist of the matter, therefore, is to use different versions of a library for GTK+ and Qt applications. Is there a way to do this?